# How to run application on server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I've recently received some ASP.NET application to test. I must run it on local server. I installed IIS with all components. I copied whole project to c:\inetpub\wwwroot. Catalog structure:

[image: img]

I suppose main file to run is Global.asax, but when i try to run localhost/.../global.asax I get error:

> HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
>   Description: The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the Multipurpose 
>   Internet Mail Extensions (MIME) map policy that is configured on the Web server. The page you requested has a file name extension that is not recognized, and is not allowed.

ASP.NET is completely new technology for me. I guess there is very easy solution ;)

Comment: Are you able to compile the project?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a virtual deirectory on IIS ad the publish your site there. You can find complete process here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS

Seems you are using MVC. so check this : http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-deploying-to-iis-as-a-test-environment-5-of-12

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Virtual Directory of your application.

Check out this [Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771804%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

You can directory publish your web application on IIS. 
Here is [walkthrough reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd483479%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).